# How to reach ftp-server by using \\ftp.server.com in "search in programs and files"

Tags: ftp

Can reach an FTP server by using the path `\\ftp.servername.com\` in the Windows 7 search box accessed via the Start Menu?

The FTP-server is running Filezilla FTP Server on a Windows 2008 server.

Comment: You can't. UNC paths are for SMB/CIFS.

Answer (score 2):

The path `\\ftp.servername.com\` is a UNC path which is used for communicating with SMB and/or CIFS. As such, it's impossible to access a server running FTP with a client using a completely unrelated protocol (unless you want to go to the trouble of stringing up some kind of crazy proxy hand-off system - and you don't).

Windows 7 has the built-in ability to access an FTP server. Go to your start menu and type in the FQDN of the FTP server including protocol. For example:

[image]

You will be presented with a dialog box to log into the server with a username and password.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Type ftp://ftp.servername.com and hit "enter".

Comment: hmm, the ftp- folder doesn´t pop up using win7 built in browsing of ftp. Using filezilla, it works like a charm.. hmmm??